Django (DRF): How can I apply authentication on this class-based view?
In my Django project I have two User Groups:

Manager
Employee

Now I'm trying to build a class-based view that returns all managers. However, it's only supposed to be accessible to managers. If an employee or an anonymous user attempts to access it, it's supposed to return a 403-HTTP-Status code.
I've built the class-based view so far and for simplicity it extends generics.ListAPIView. But I can't find a way to apply the desired authentication.
I have removed the "Can view group" and "Can view user" permissions from the Employee group, so no employee can view the managers. I've tried several permission_classes, but everytime I sent a GET-request containing an employee's token via Insomnia, it returned the managers instead of a 403-Status code.
Help is greatly appreciated.
Here's the code of the view:
class ViewManager(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions]
    group = Group.objects.get(name='Manager')
    users = group.user_set.all()
    queryset = users
    serializer_class = ManagerSerializer


This question is similar to: Django Rest Framework use DjangoModelPermissions on ListAPIView. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Answers here suggest non-generic approach which is fine for a single view, but doesn't scale well. Refer to a linked duplicate for a more traditional approach.

To give access permission on a view to a specific group name, the command you could use is:
def my_view(request):
   if request.user.groups.filter(name='Manager').exists(): 
      print("User is Manager")

You can make a custom permission class:
from rest_framework import permissions
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class IsManager(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated: # Exclude anonymous users
            return False
        return request.user.groups.filter(name='Manager').exists()

and you could use it like this:
class ViewManager(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsManager]
    ...


You can make a custom permission class like so DRF Permission docs
class HasManagerPerms(permissions.BasePermission):
      def has_permission(self, request, view):
          if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_manager
             return True

and add this to your view like so
permission_classes = [HasManagerPerms]




 

